# How do I know if HWND is desktop itself?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I use GetForegroundWindow to get the foreground window handle but if there is no window, then it returns the HWND to the desktop. How do I know if the HWND is the desktop?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Compare it with the result of calling [GetDesktopWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633504%28VS.85%29.aspx)().

Answer (score 7):

Compare the handle with the handle returned by GetDesktopWindow().